# How to remove print/ markings from small Eye Drops bottle for other use?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, kitchen, bathroom, storage

I am not sure what the material of these types of small bottles is composed of.

[image: eye drops dropper small tiny bottle]

I find they are most reliable when it comes to being Leak resistant for small quantity of liquids etc where I just need a drop or two for use.

Two ways that come straight to mind are scratching the print off using some blade or sand paper like items; stone/ brick surface?

Or Use some solvent that can dissolve / remove the print without affecting the material of the bottle.

I have gathered several of these so easier & faster tried & tested methods is good

---

**Updated** as per Stan's comment & insight about bottom of bottle info:

[image: eye dropper bottle bottom material spec]

Comment: @Stan you're the man. I'm sure you get that a lot. Ha ha! So here's the spec, and I'm reading it via iPhone magnifier as LDPE or LDNE or something like that

Comment: Oh wow, someone got upset and gave a negative for this question. I wonder why

Comment: Usually, the type of plastic can be found encoded with a number on the bottom of the container with a triangle. The plastic may or may not be suitable for liquids that replace the original stuff. EDIT: You show #5 and also "LDPE" which is Low Density PolyEthylene. There are 7 types of plastic containers sharing this system of ID.

Comment: @Stan - Thats very knowledgeable - Could you guide/ link to a list and point what might a good "cleaner" for the Print/ Markings. I might as well get that removed in the meantime and then figure out if the Oil would be okay for usage in it.

Comment: Here's a great solvent you can try: [Goofoff](https://www.amazon.com/Goof-FG661-Professional-Strength-Remover/dp/B01DA0IWL0/).  If sanding, use a lower grit to level, then high grit to resurface (or rub with baking soda paste).

Answer (score 4):

Look closely at the printing to see if some has already rubbed-off during use.
 Yes? The container is made cheaply for temporary use and the printing can be removed with only light scratching with something like your finger nail.
No? Polypropylene and Low Density Polyethylene are tough and screen printing has been used formulated to stick to it.
Try some aggressive household stuff such as oven cleaner which contains lye, turpentine which is a common paint solvent. There's even a slight chance that some of the liquids you want to substitute will dissolve the printing on the container.
Good Luck.

Comment: A less aggressive pre-cursor to using oven cleaner: try nail-polish remover. If you don't have that, then pure ethyl acetate or pure acetone may be available from a pharmacy.

Comment: @owjburnham Yes. I didn't mention nail-polish remover since the price is ridiculous for the amount of acetone (with added denaturing conditioner and fragrances) that comes in the container.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a workaround that solves the implied problem in your question: "How can I **hide** the printing on a small eyedrop bottle?" My solution is to simply cover it, with one of the following:

- duct tape (which solves everything!)
- masking tape
- a blank white mailing label
- nail polish or something similar (but make sure it's flexible and won't crack)

Comment: That wouldn't have warranted a question as I have stickers and permanent markers that can write and overwrite. Because I'm using oils these can get messy. And I prefer clear view to see how much oil and also when I'm pouring in and/ or drops out

Comment: Objective was not to hide but to Clear for visibility. I know the oils and see them by colour etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try different solvents, starting with acetone.  If acetone doesn't work, try MEK.  HOWEVER, why not just buy new bottles?  You could try ebay, or if you're in the USA, try The Cary Company.

I recently bought an air nailer that came with a small bottle of air tool oil, just like your picture except no printed writing or labels of any kind.  I'm sure you can buy the bottles cheaply, and not risk contaminating your oils, etc.